# Sugar CRM - Java Client - login

Tags: java, authentication, sugarcrm

I was trying to develop a Java application which gets contacts from Sugar CRM. I have newly installed Sugar CRM 6.0.2 and I did not make any modifications to it. I am making use of the inbuilt SOAP based WebServices (have to use soap cant go for rest based) to login. But while logging in I am getting an error message saying:

```
anyType{
    id=-1; 
    error=anyType{
        number=10; 
        name=Invalid Login; 
        description=Login attempt failed please check the username and password;
    };
}
```

I am sending a string `user` for `user_auth` parameter:

1. `String user = "user_auth{username=will; password=18218139eec55d83cf82679934e5cd75; version=1.0;}";`
2. `String user = "{'user_auth':{'username':'will','password':'18218139eec55d83cf82679934e5cd75', 'version':'1.0'}}";`

I tried both of the above options and its not working. I tried "SugarCRM" and "CRM" for `application_name`.

If anyone of you can help me regarding this that would be a great helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, code example (including how you do the SOAP call) would help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in SugarCRM. You may only log into the WebServices with Admin.

And you can't pass JSON Strings to SOAP. You have to pass XML using SOAP.

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/SOAP/PHP/Logging_In